# Spring authentication with JWT returning 403

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, jwt

I am trying to use Spring Security in my REST API using JWT tokens but everytime I am trying to make a login using the endpoint: /login of my Api, I am getting a 403 Forbidden and I have no idea why, with a completely empty body message.

This is my WebSecurity extenson configuration:

```
package com.debtServer.authentication;

import org.springframework.http.HttpMethod;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.config.http.SessionCreationPolicy;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.web.cors.CorsConfiguration;
import org.springframework.web.cors.CorsConfigurationSource;
import org.springframework.web.cors.UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;

@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurity extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;
    private BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder;

    public WebSecurity(UserDetailsServiceImpl userDetailsService, BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder) {
        this.userDetailsService = userDetailsService;
        this.bCryptPasswordEncoder = bCryptPasswordEncoder;
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.cors().and().csrf().disable().authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, SecurityConstants.SIGN_UP_URL).permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .addFilter(new JWTAuthenticationFilter(authenticationManager()))
                .addFilter(new JWTAuthorizationFilter(authenticationManager()))
                // this disables session creation on Spring Security
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(bCryptPasswordEncoder);
    }

    @Bean
    CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
        final UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", new CorsConfiguration().applyPermitDefaultValues());
        return source;
    }
}
```

And the following two classes are the two filteres configured:

```
package com.debtServer.authentication;

import io.jsonwebtoken.Jwts;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken;
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter;

import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class JWTAuthorizationFilter extends BasicAuthenticationFilter {

    public JWTAuthorizationFilter(AuthenticationManager authManager) {
        super(authManager);
    }

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest req,
                                    HttpServletResponse res,
                                    FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        String header = req.getHeader(SecurityConstants.HEADER_STRING);
        if (header == null || !header.startsWith(SecurityConstants.TOKEN_PREFIX)) {
            chain.doFilter(req, res);
            return;
        }
        UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authentication = getAuthentication(req);

        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
        chain.doFilter(req, res);
    }

    private UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken getAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request) {
        String token = request.getHeader(SecurityConstants.HEADER_STRING);
        if (token != null) {
            // parse the token.
            String user = Jwts.parser()
                    .setSigningKey(SecurityConstants.SECRET.getBytes())
                    .parseClaimsJws(token.replace(SecurityConstants.TOKEN_PREFIX, ""))
                    .getBody()
                    .getSubject();

            if (user != null) {
                return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(user, null, new ArrayList<>());
            }
            return null;
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Second filter:

```
package com.debtServer.authentication;

import com.debtServer.model.LoginBindingModel;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import io.jsonwebtoken.Jwts;
import io.jsonwebtoken.SignatureAlgorithm;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken;
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.security.core.AuthenticationException;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter;

import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;

import static com.debtServer.authentication.SecurityConstants.*;
import com.debtServer.persistence.entity.*;
public class JWTAuthenticationFilter extends UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter {
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    public JWTAuthenticationFilter(AuthenticationManager authenticationManager) {
        this.authenticationManager = authenticationManager;
    }

    @Override
    public Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest req,
                                                HttpServletResponse res) throws AuthenticationException {
        try {
            LoginBindingModel loginCredentials = new ObjectMapper()
                    .readValue(req.getInputStream(), LoginBindingModel.class);

             return authenticationManager.authenticate(
                    new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                            loginCredentials.getUsername(),
                            loginCredentials.getPassword(),
                            new ArrayList<>())
            );
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void successfulAuthentication(HttpServletRequest req,
                                            HttpServletResponse res,
                                            FilterChain chain,
                                            Authentication auth) throws IOException, ServletException {
        String token = Jwts.builder()
                .setSubject(((User) auth.getPrincipal()).getUsername())
                .setExpiration(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + EXPIRATION_TIME))
                .signWith(SignatureAlgorithm.HS512, SECRET.getBytes())
                .compact();
        res.addHeader(HEADER_STRING, TOKEN_PREFIX + token);
    }
}
```

And finally my implementation of the user details:

```
package com.debtServer.authentication;

import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UsernameNotFoundException;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import com.debtServer.persistence.repository.UserRepository;
import com.debtServer.persistence.entity.*;

import java.util.List;

import static java.util.Collections.emptyList;

@Service
public class UserDetailsServiceImpl implements UserDetailsService {
    private UserRepository applicationUserRepository;

    public UserDetailsServiceImpl(UserRepository applicationUserRepository) {
        this.applicationUserRepository = applicationUserRepository;
    }

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        UserEntity applicationUser = applicationUserRepository.findByNEmail(username);
        if (applicationUser == null) {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException(username);
        }
        return new User(applicationUser.getUsername(), applicationUser.getPassword(), emptyList());
    }
}
```

I am using Spring Security.

Update: I have found an error in my console:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:582) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:185) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:496) ~[na:na]
    at io.jsonwebtoken.impl.Base64Codec.encode(Base64Codec.java:21) ~[jjwt-0.9.0.jar:0.9.0]
    at io.jsonwebtoken.impl.Base64UrlCodec.encode(Base64UrlCodec.java:22) ~[jjwt-0.9.0.jar:0.9.0]
    at io.jsonwebtoken.impl.DefaultJwtBuilder.base64UrlEncode(DefaultJwtBuilder.java:349) ~[jjwt-0.9.0.jar:0.9.0]
    at io.jsonwebtoken.impl.DefaultJwtBuilder.compact(DefaultJwtBuilder.java:295) ~[jjwt-0.9.0.jar:0.9.0]
    at com.debtServer.authentication.JWTAuthenticationFilter.successfulAuthentication(JWTAuthenticationFilter.java:58) ~[classes/:na]
```

Line 58 is this one: `.compact();`

Comment: what HTTP verb are you using to request `/login`? POST right?

Comment: @JorgeL.Morla yes

Comment: I was reading a bit more about what is going on and I am now in possession of some more information. Basically I am getting 403 because of an exception. Details in the main post

Answer (score 1):

I have just find out the problem. The problem was I was using Java 9, which seems not to be compatible with some of the extensions I was using. I changed to 8 and it is now ok.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you missed csrf token. Spring security default csrf configuration value is  enabled and without csrf token spring security returns 403 status.

Here's what is csrf and how to add csrf token. :
https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html/csrf.html#csrf-using

Comment: I've provided aditional info to the problem

Answer (score 0):

Add the dependency inside pom.xml below to solve the problem.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
     <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.0</version>
 </dependency>
```